# ZXing barcode scanner library giving camera error in Android 6.0 devices

Tags: android, zxing, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have integrated ZXing barcode scanner library in my app.And I am handling the request permission dialogs for Android 6.0 devices.But my issue is when I am selecting 'Deny' in the request permission dialog am getting an  error like below image.If I click on 'Allow' app is working fine.Can anyone help me.I am scratching my head for a long time to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.[[image][image: ][1]]

The below is my code snippet in which I am handling the permission request for Marshmallow.

```
if (version >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SearchActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SearchActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);

                    } else {

                        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SearchActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);


                    }
                }
            }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                int version3 = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                 Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Camera is required",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And the below is my error log.

```
08-23 10:49:07.894   9832-10612/com.test.xxx E/CameraInstance﹕ Failed to open camera
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
        at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:511)
        at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:353)
        at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.OpenCameraInterface.open(OpenCameraInterface.java:83)
        at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.camera.CameraManager.open(CameraManager.java:121)
        at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.camera.CameraInstance$3.run(CameraInstance.java:158)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

08-23 10:49:09.268   9832-10668/com.test.ecommercetrial E/CameraInstance﹕ Failed to configure camera
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference
        at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.camera.CameraManager.setParameters(CameraManager.java:353)
        at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.camera.CameraManager.configure(CameraManager.java:139)
        at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.camera.CameraInstance$4.run(CameraInstance.java:171)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Share your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: vote to close off topic: seeking debug needs posting the relevant code and error logs

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem? If camara use is denied, what should ZXing do instead?

Comment: As a developer I have to check all possible condition a user can use the app.While we are denying the permission,the app showing an error message will affect its performance.If you really wanna to know about the scenario just install the Barcode Scanner app by ZXing in a marshmallow device and turn off camera permission in app settings and run the app.It will show an error if we deny.For information mine is an ecommerce app.Not just only for barcode scanning.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your gradle with latest marshmallow version number. hope it will solve the issue.